# KELLY, MIKE, ET AL.V.PENNSYLVANIA, ET AL

Tags: word-meaning

Does "V." stand for "Versus"?

> Tuesady, December 8, 2020
> Order In Pending Case
> 20A98    **KELLY, MIKE, ET AL.V.PENNSYLVANIA, ET AL.**
> The application for injunctive relief presented to Justice Alito by him referred to the Court is denied.

> [Source](https://twitter.com/SCOTUSblog/status/1336428598568349702/photo/1)

Comment: Yes.  This is a very common abbreviation in a legal case.

Comment: ... and in a sports match.

Comment: Yes. I hope somebody can expand this into a full answer specifically tailored to our site, but here's something to draw from on our sister site: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/366269/116151